# Utilização de Há ou a

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia, gramática, uso-de-palavras

Quando se deve utilizar "há" ou "a"?

> Ele procurava por sua amada há anos.
>
> Ele procurava por sua amada a anos.
>
> Não o vejo a dias
>
> Não o vejo há dias
>
> Há uma criança correndo no parque.
>
> A uma criança correndo no parque.

Comment: Em todos esses casos o correto é há.

Comment: Fernando, no título está «a» (artigo definido feminino singular) mas na pergunta está «á». Sobre qual deles queres perguntar? Ou será que queres perguntar pelos 3 - «há», «á», e «a»?

Comment: Era sobre o «a» . Não percebi que estava com acento desculpe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os casos exemplificados são com H, segue a regra para melhor entender o motivo:

> Para saber se você deve usar “a” ou “há” apresentamos aqui algumas
>   dicas para facilitar a eliminação de dúvidas a esse respeito:
>
> • Usa-se “há” quando o verbo “haver” é impessoal, tem sentido de
>   “existir” e é conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular.
>
> Exemplo: Há um modo mais fácil de fazer essa massa de bolo. Existe um
>   modo mais fácil de fazer essa massa de bolo.
>
> • Ainda como impessoal, o verbo “haver” é utilizado em expressões que
>   indicam tempo decorrido, assim como o verbo “fazer”.
>
> Exemplos: Há muito tempo não como esse bolo. Faz muito tempo que não
>   como esse bolo.
>
> Logo, para identificarmos se utilizaremos o “a” ou “há” substituímos
>   por “faz” nas expressões indicativas de tempo. Se a substituição não
>   alterar o sentido real da frase, emprega-se “há”.
>
> Exemplos: Há cinco anos não escutava uma música como essa.
>   Substituindo por faz: Faz cinco anos que não escutava uma música como
>   essa.
>
> • Quando não for possível a conjugação do verbo “haver” nem no sentido
>   de “existir”, nem de “tempo decorrido”, então, emprega-se “a”.
>
> Exemplos: Daqui a pouco você poderá ir embora. Estamos a dez minutos
>   de onde você está.
>
> Importante: Não se usa “Há muitos anos atrás”, pois é redundante,
>   pleonasmo. Não é necessário colocar “atrás”, uma vez que o verbo
>   “haver” está no sentido de tempo decorrido.

Fonte: [Brasil Escola](http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/a-ou-ha.htm)

A pode ser usado como preposição em alguns casos quando estamos falando de tempo:

> Já na frase “Estamos a dois minutos de casa”, o A deve ser escrito sem
>   agá, pois não pode ser substituído por um verbo. Não tem sentido
>   dizer: "Estamos faz dois minutos de casa" ou "Estamos existem dois
>   minutos de casa".

Fonte: [G1 - Dicas de Português](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/quando-usar-ha-ou.html)

Comment: Muito bom. Concordo com tudo.